# How do you configure browserify to work with gulp?

Tags: javascript, gulp, browserify

I can't use gulp-browserify. My input file is  _/components/js/script.js (this has require('jquery').    I want it to output to _/js/script.js.  What's wrong with my configuration?  I get a path error.

```
var gulp = require('gulp'), 
    sass =  require('gulp-sass'), 
    uglify = require('gulp-uglify'),
    browserify= require('browserify'); 



gulp.task('watch', function(){
    gulp.watch('_/components/sass/*.scss', ['sass']);

});

gulp.task('browserify', function(){
    var b = browserify({entries: './_/components/js/script.js', debug: true}); 

    return b.bundle()
            .pipe(gulp.dest('./js/'));
});

gulp.task('default', ['sass', 'browserify', 'watch']);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't pipe `browserify` bundle stream like that to a `gulp.dest` stream. It's expecting a vinyl stream. You could use `vinyl-source-stream` to transform it. This is very common:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    browserify = require('browserify'),
    source = require('vinyl-source-stream');

var files = ['./js/admin.js', './js/login.js', './js/main.js']

gulp.task('browserify', function(){
    var b = browserify(files);
    b.bundle()
    .pipe(source('bundle.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('public'))
});
```